# Flask API callback to web page via Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, python, web-services, flask

Currently I have a working Flask API.
It performs asynchronous jobs.

Example: Server synchronization:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "force": true }' http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/1.0/host/1
```

I return:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 ACCEPTED
< Server: gunicorn/19.3.0
< Date: Sun, 08 May 2016 20:56:23 GMT
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 25
< Location: http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/1.0/job/52E49C9915
< Status: http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/1.0/status/52E49C9915
< 
{
  "job": "52E49C9915"
```

I provide location URL using `Flask url_for` and continue executing the job in the background. This process can take between 10 seconds to 45 seconds. Via the API we can always access the Location or Status URL to see the Job status.

In Web page today we perform the Javascript/PHP request call and display a notification when we received the 202 Accepted.

[image: Synchronization]

Since Job runs in the background what would be the best option to notify the web page when Job is completed?. 
I though of performing the JS async call and give it a limit of 45 seconds in client side and then check URL for job status but is not very efficient as the process could be faster maybe 10 seconds. Ideally I would like the API notify the Web application.
What would be the recommend option? A callback URL?, and have Flask API notify a Web server URL when job is completed? 
What would be the technology/sample code to use. 
My web application is pure PHP, JS and Apache.

Comment: One option if HTTP long-polling; a better alternative (in my opinion) is something using sockets – then you can have two-way communication, which allows you to notify the user that an update has occurred.

Comment: You could try server side events: https://github.com/DazWorrall/flask-sse less work then sockets, more robust then long polling just one way communication though